# Using variable vs. using number

Tags: c++, c, assembly

Imagine a function in those versions:

```cpp
int faculty(const unsigned int n) {
    return n == 1 ? n : n * faculty(n - 1);
}
```

```cpp
int faculty(const unsigned int n) {
    return n == 1 ? 1 : n * faculty(n - 1);
}
```

The only difference is that I return `n` in the first and `1` in the second one, depending on `n`. The result is the same but is there any other difference you could be aware of while ignoring the significance?

I know there is a high chance the compiler will make the same assembly instructions out of it, but hey, I'm just curious.

Comment: Did you try compiling the code and comaring the resulting assembly?  Hint: use `gcc -S`.

Comment: GCC 7.1 and newer, with `-O2`, even [de-duplicates the code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GPp6rr)

Comment: The second version contains the magic number *twice*.

Comment: @WeatherVane true, but actually it is two different magic numbers that happen to have the same value, one is the stop condition and the other is what is returned when the stop condition is hit. Imho the second is more readable because that `n` can never be anything but `1`

Comment: @idclev463035818 in that case the first one using `n` is misleading, appearing to be the same.

Comment: @WeatherVane indeed agree

Comment: @harold Thank you for the link! The compiler is actually so smart that it recognizes both functions to be identical and jumps from the second to the first one. When I look at them one after another they get compiled to the exact same instructions.

Comment: @akuzminykh Rather, it turns out that the clang compiler is so dumb that it goes haywire - can you explain this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60773870/what-is-clang-trying-to-do-optimizing-this-simple-recursive-algorithm

Comment: @Lundin: "the compiler" in that statement was referring to recent GCC -O2 in @ harold's link.  Not *all compilers*.  It is useful to point out that multiple C++ implementations exist and are widely used in real life, and don't all optimize the same way, but the OP's statement was not wrong IMO.  I would have chosen different phrasing to point that out.

Comment: Minor: The first attempts to return an `unsigned` or `unsigned` and then convert to `int`.  The second attempts to return an `int` or `unsigned` and then convert to `int`.  I'd recommend to only use 1 type (`unsigned`) for this sample code to set aside such inconsistencies that may muddle the optimization and make for a cleaner apples-to-apples comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been pointed out in comments, [gcc will recognise the two to be identical](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GPp6rr). For what clang does to the code there is a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60773870/what-is-clang-trying-to-do-optimizing-this-simple-recursive-algorithm). Apart from clang going havoc, the difference is cosmetic.

---

There is however a subtle problem in your code. `factorial(0)` will make `n-1` wrap around and recurse till it arrives at `n==1` just to return the wrong value: `0` from a `0 * faculty(-1U)` in the top-level `n==0` call.  (`0!` is defined to be `1`).

This is a overly verbose correct version:

```
int faculty(const unsigned int n) {
    const unsigned int stop_when_n_leq = 1;
    const int return_at_stop = 1;
    return n <= stop_when_n_leq ? return_at_stop : n * faculty(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: "_`factorial(0)` will make `n-1` wrap around and recurse till it arrives at `n==1` just to return the wrong value: `0`_" - It would return `1` if it could recurse that deep, wouldn't it? Still, the total result would be very wrong :-) Not my downvote btw.

Comment: @TedLyngmo first iteration is `0 * faculty(-1)`

Comment: Ah, ok, by "_return the wrong value_" I thought you meant that the function would return the wrong value.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it does, `0!` is defined to be `1` not `0`

Comment: @user253751 maybe I should have made this more clear. I am not suggesting to name these constants in this particular function. I just wanted to point out that they are magic numbers and took the example to illulstrate how naming them can avoid mistakes like the one OP made. Anyhow, also in real code I wouldn't mind to name them. If you think its worth a downvote, fine with me

Comment: @idclev463035818 How come you left the other `1` alone and didn't define `const int recursion_increment = -1;`?

Comment: @user253751 you didnt get my point and I have the feeling you dont want to. OP made a mistake because their `factulty(0)` return `0` which is wrong. I pointed to that and speculated why they made the mistake and showed a way how that mistake could have been avoided. There is no reason to discuss the `-1` decrement, unless you want to troll me

Comment: @idclev463035818 They could've also made a mistake with the decrement amount, couldn't they? They should write `const int recursion_increment = -1;` to avoid that mistake.

Comment: @idclev463035818 If your technique for avoiding mistakes requires you to know what mistakes you are going to make, then...

Comment: I'd suggest `n <= 1` as the base-case to properly handle the `0!` case while saving an iteration for all higher inputs.

Comment: @user253751 you made it quite clear from the beginning that you dont like the answer, I don't like it enough to keep defening it, so this is going nowhere.

Comment: "Magic numbers" usually refer to constants *other* than 0, 1, and -1. I don't like the idea of seeing lengthy identifiers in the code instead of 0, 1, and -1 -- because it *reduces* readability by adding clutter. I disagree with the basic advice this answer gives.

Comment: @DevSolar it is ok to disagree. Regarding readability, imho neither the first nor the second version of OP are optimal, because in the first there is a `n` that can only ever be `1` and in the second there are two different `1`s. Actually I'd be ok with the second, but not the first. The real answer to the question is the first sentence and I already regret it to say any more than that, because it is too opinion based. I even considered to delete the answer, because ony the first sentence is a bit too slim for an answer, but as it is accepted I cannot.

Comment: @DevSolar coming back after some time, I have to agree with you. Bringing magic numbers to the table was silly. I removed that part eventually

Comment: @DevSolar feels good to accept that I was wrong, should do that more often :P